# Causative verb usage with must

Tags: grammaticality, causative-have

Can we use causative have with modal must.
Suppose

1. you must have had those document published by you.
2. you must have the documents prepared by someone.

Are these idiomatic and grammatical. actually i am experimenting with these.

Comment: Yes, you can - although your first sentence requires **documents** (plural) and needs to drop **by you**. Your second sentence is fine. The first sentence is saying that it is you who had the documents published. The second is saying that it is necessary for you to get someone to prepare the documents.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, although this grammar has a fairly specific usage.  Ordinarily it expresses a perceived reason for something, for example:

> These documents **must have been written** by you, (because ...)
>
> These documents **must have been prepared** by someone else (because ...)

This can also be used to describe a situation:

> "She **must have come** here before us -- look, you can see the tracks of her shoes in the snow!" Edward shouted.  "Quick, don't let her get away!"

or a person:

> [Oh you **must've been** a beautiful baby
>
>   'Cause baby look at you now](https://youtu.be/Lk-wTeDXJCk?t=39)